# Drawing neat UML class diagrams with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw (UML) class diagrams with tikz (and I'm aware there is a special tikz package for that). I want to imitate the style that [yuml.me](http://yuml.me) uses, since personally I find it very appealing and at the same time still serious. Here is an example what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Note in particular that there is a slight shadow/glow outside and inside the border and the subtle color gradient used for the fill color.

Here is a zoomed view to make clear what I mean:

[image]

I tried to take the color values from an yuml diagram and transfer them to tikz, but the closest I got is the following:

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{class}=[
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    text centered,
    anchor=north,
    text=black,
    text width=3cm,
    shading=axis,
    bottom color={rgb:red,222;green,222;blue,222},top color=white,shading angle=45]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (Item) [class, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
    {
        \textbf{Car}
        \nodepart{second}foobar\newline baz
    };      
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which is still pretty ugly and not anywhere near the style I want to achieve.

Any help from the tikz-experts would be appriciated!

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

[image]

Just replace your older bottom color definition with `bottom color=black!20`. Change that number to increase or decrease the saturation.

Comment: Well the bottom color I used is the one from the original png - but for whatever reason, tikz produces r:85g:85b:85 with my definition (which clearly is not 222). Why? Also, do you have any idea how to reproduce the soft borders?

Comment: Not sure, but you can set what *red, blue and green* look like. Add this in your preamble: `\definecolor{red}{RGB}{200,5,5}`. Red is the "command name", so whenever you write red, it will use the RGB commands you gave. For this reason, I'd use customized names, like "myred" and so on. :) What do you mean by soft borders? Sorry can't get that. :P

Comment: If you open the target png with an image editor and zoom in, you will see that the border is not just a 1px black line (which tikz produces at the moment) but there is an inner and an outer border as well, that's what I mean with soft borders.

Comment: @Mef I'm looking into it. :)

Comment: @Mef Are you that's not an illusion from the shadow in the original picture by the way? :P When I zoom in the image loses quality.

Comment: Yep, 100% sure, see my edit. If you can't see any differences, you should probably check your screen configuration :P

Comment: @Mef The “soft border” looks like anti-aliasing. The same can be observed with the text “User”. The shadow can be achieved with TikZ, looks like a `drop shadow`. However I would advise against any fancy coloring as it looks neither good nor professional (in my opinion). The zigzaged lines from the examples look even worse.

Comment: @Mef I see what you posted in your main question by the way. Not sure how to apply anti-aliasing, but I agree with Qrrbrbirlbel, keep it sober! :D

Answer (score 1):

Just as  Alenanno's suggestion,use define color marco will resolve the color issue.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\definecolor{bottomcol}{RGB}{222,222,222}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{class}=[
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    text centered,
    anchor=north,
    text=black,
    text width=3cm,
    shading=axis,
    bottom color=bottomcol,top color=white,shading angle=45]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (Item) [class, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
    {
        \textbf{Car}
        \nodepart{second}foobar\newline baz
    };      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]